How do you properly set up an nis server if you're trying to share users on a lAN?
I am very new to ubuntu and networking in general. In my networking class i have to set up an nis server. what we're trying to do is share accounts in a local network.
in my /etc/bind/db.example.com i have added nis-server IN A . my domainname is example.com. I then in my /etc/hosts file added the  "127.0.0.1 nis-server.example.com" entry.
we were thne given the https://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=Ubuntu_22.04&p=nis&f=1 website to go to and follow the steps are.
one of the first steps there is:
root@dlp:~# vi /etc/default/nis.
Initially in class i backed out of loading the nis two or three times because i thought it'd frozen with how long it was taken. But because i did that, i encountered a dpkg error requiring the usage of --configure -a to manually install. Since then, everything has gone downhill. I've been turning to ai and i'm at a loss.
for one: every time i try to use dpkg configure -a it returns an error about how i do not have the /usr/sbin/yppasswdd file or directory. Cool! so i go to install the yppasswdd manually and it says it cannot be found. i've gone and tried changing what sources my ubuntu can install from and i'm still getting NOTHING! it says packet unrecognized /unable to be located. Because i don't have the packet nothing is working for me!
when i use sudo apt-get install -f, which is supposed to repair files, it says error with the dpkg. when i run the configure, it says error! couldn't find  /usr/sbin/yppasswdd. i've uninstalled, i've tried purging the files. nothing is working for me.
i feel like somewhere is some half-baked  code file that i messed up by not letting it install properly. I'm so frustrated right now! Please, if anyone has any clue on how to figure this out i'd appreciate it a lot! i'd start over completely fresh but the thing is we've spent two to three weeks etablishing a dns server and running tests using it. i'm really afraid to go back through and get a server running and all of that because this is my first ever computer administration class.
please help!
